# Sum of the fields from multiple records of the group

Tags: xslt

I am trying to take a difference value of the amount deleted and the amount added to report the amount adjusted in my example below. I get the amount field in two different record. I want to substract amount 1 from record 1 with amount 2 of record 2 if the code for both match and one is a deleted record and the other is an added record.
And print only the added record with the calculated amount.

Here is my input xml

```
    <employee>
        <Compensation_One_Time_Payment isDeleted="1">
            <External_Payroll_Code>6090</External_Payroll_Code>
            <Earning_or_Deduction>E</Earning_or_Deduction>
            <Amount>100</Amount>
        </Compensation_One_Time_Payment>
        <Compensation_One_Time_Payment isAdded="1">
            <External_Payroll_Code>6090</External_Payroll_Code>
            <Earning_or_Deduction>E</Earning_or_Deduction>
            <Amount>200</Amount>
        </Compensation_One_Time_Payment>
        <Compensation_One_Time_Payment isAdded="1">
            <External_Payroll_Code>1111</External_Payroll_Code>
            <Earning_or_Deduction>E</Earning_or_Deduction>
            <Amount>300</Amount>
        </Compensation_One_Time_Payment>
    </employee>


My xslt is
```

Delete
                    
                
                
                    
                        
                        Add

```
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$OTP_Group/root/OTP" group-by='concat(External_Payroll_Code,Action)'>
            <xsl:variable name="AdjustedAmount">
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(OTP[Action='Add']/Amount) - sum(OTP[Action='Delete']/Amount)"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <OTP>
            <code>
                <xsl:value-of select="External_Payroll_Code"/> 
            </code>
            <NewAmount>
                <xsl:value-of select="$AdjustedAmount"/>
            </NewAmount>
            </OTP>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please advise.

My current output is. The input will contain more than one record per code and I want to calculate amounts per code. But for the grouping by code since I am already in the for each, I cannot now look at the other record in the same group.

Current Output:

```
<OTP>
   <code>6090</code>
   <NewAmount>0</NewAmount>
</OTP>
<OTP>
   <code>6090</code>
   <NewAmount>0</NewAmount>
</OTP>
<OTP>
   <code>1111</code>
   <NewAmount>0</NewAmount>
</OTP>
```

Expected output

```
 <OTP>
       <code>6090</code>
       <NewAmount>100</NewAmount>
    </OTP>
    <OTP>
       <code>1111</code>
       <NewAmount>300</NewAmount>
    </OTP>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your expected output? Thank you.

Comment: edited, added expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be grouping purely `External_Payroll_Code` (as you want one `OTP` per employee), so the `xsl:for-each-group` should be like this...

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="$OTP_Group/root/OTP" group-by='External_Payroll_Code'>
```

Additionally, to get the total amount, you need to be summing over elements in the current-group

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()[Action='Add']/Amount) - sum(current-group()[Action='Delete']/Amount)"/>
```

However, you really don't need to create a variable here. I can't see the benefit of adding an `Action` node as you can just as easily query on the relevant attributes in the `xsl:for-each-group` anyway.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs " version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="employee">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Compensation_One_Time_Payment" group-by='External_Payroll_Code'>
            <OTP>
            <code>
                <xsl:value-of select="External_Payroll_Code"/> 
            </code>
            <NewAmount>
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()[@isAdded='1']/Amount) - sum(current-group()[@isDeleted='1']/Amount)"/>
            </NewAmount>
            </OTP>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Silly me. I missed the point, you are right, I could just use the current group and identify by the attribute. I did not need the additional tags. Thank you so much for the quickest response. Highly appreciate your advise.